# Perl: using an array to capitalize words

Tags: string, perl

I'm treating large blocks of all-caps text, converting them to mixed case and adding punctuation. However, there's a large set of words and names that I want to capitalize, such as days of the week, months, people, and so on.

Rather than using a giant glob of substitutions, is there a way to use an array or hash of properly capitalized terms somehow? So if I have a string "and then on monday, we should see bob and sue" to convert it to "and then on Monday, we should see Bob and Sue" if I have the terms stored in an array or hash?

Thanks!

Comment: See [`Lingua::EN::Titlecase`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Lingua::EN::Titlecase)

Answer (score 2):

```
use feature qw( fc );  # Alternatively, "lc" is "close enough".

my @to_capitalize = qw( Monday Bob Sue );
my @abbreviations = qw( USA );
my @exceptions    = qw( iPhone );

my %words = (
   ( map { fc($_) => ucfirst(lc($_)) } @to_capitalize ),
   ( map { fc($_) => uc($_)          } @abbreviations ),
   ( map { fc($_) => $_              } @exceptions ),
);

my $pat =
   join '|',
      #map quotemeta,    # If this is needed, our use of \b is incorrect.
         keys %words;

s/\b($pat)\b/$words{fc($1)}/ig;
```

Adjust as needed.

Comment: You need a comma after `join '|'` -- you've commented it out! And this won't compile without `use feature 'fc'` or `use v5.16`

Comment: @Borodin, Thanks, fixed. You can also use `CORE::fc` instead of using the feature.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a hash of words to transformations, then if you encounter those words apply the expected transformation:

```
use strict;
use warnings; 

use feature qw(say);

my %transformations = (
   monday => \&titlecase,
   bob    => \&titlecase,
   sue    => \&titlecase,
   shout  => \&uppercase,
);

while ( my $line = <$filehandle> ) {
   chomp $line;
   foreach my $word ( split /\s+/, $line ) {
      if ( my $transform = $transformations{lc $word} ) {
         $line =~ s/$word/$transform->($word)/ge;
      }
   }
   say $line;
}

sub titlecase {
   my ($s) = @_;

   return ucfirst lc $s;
}

sub uppercase {
   my ($s) = @_;

   return uc $s;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the great ideas. I ended up using the idea of a hash (for the first time!). This may not be very optimal but it gets the job done :)

```
%capitalize = (
"usa" => "USA",
"nfl" => "NFL",
);

$row = "I live in the usa and love me some nfl.";

foreach my $key (keys %capitalize) {
    if ($row =~ $key) { 
        $row =~ s/$key/$capitalize{$key}/g;
        }
}

print $row;
```